# How to zip multiple data instead of multiple images?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to zip the data in memory. I am using Gzip framework for that it’s working fine but I don't want to store single image Data. I want to send more than 10 images data to append into mutable data and trying to zip. But the problem was the GZIp function returns Data. How to append multiple images data and called the Gzip function.

GZIp Function for zipping the single image data :

> **public func gzipped(level: Gzip.CompressionLevel = default) throws
>   -> Data**

This Is my code to zip two images data:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "test")
let image2 = UIImage(named: "test12")
var sampleDataOne = image2?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
var sampleDataTwo = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
var zipMutableData = NSMutableData()

do {
      zipMutableData.append(sampleDataOne)
      zipMutableData.append(sampleDataTwo)
      var resultData = try (zipMutableData.gzipped(level: .defaultCompression)) as! NSMutableData
} catch let error{
      print(error)         
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Value of type 'NSMutableData' has no member 'gzipped'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can downcast as `Data` as below to call the `gzipped` method,

```
var resultData = try (zipMutableData as Data).gzipped(level: .defaultCompression)
```

Example,

```
let zipMutableData = NSMutableData()

zipMutableData.append("Steve".data(using: .utf8)!)
zipMutableData.append("Jobs".data(using: .utf8)!)

print(String(data: zipMutableData as Data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

**Output**

```
SteveJobs
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use `NSMutableData` here. Just use `Data`:

```
var zipMutableData = sampleDataOne + sampleDataTwo
```

There's also no reason for the `as! NSMutableData` when assigning `resultData`. Just let it be `Data`.